# Show that one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homemorphic to the $2$-sphere.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752505/homeomorphism-between-compactification-of-real-line-and-unit-circle/753499#753499) answer, I can see that to show that for the $2$-dimensional case, I can use

$$
t\mapsto\begin{cases} (x,y)=\left( \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2} \right) & \text{if }t\ne\infty, \\[10pt]
(x,y)=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \left( \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2} \right) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

But what about the $3$-dimensional case? I feel like it should look something like this:

$$
t\mapsto\begin{cases} (x,y,z)=\left( \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}, t \right) & \text{if }t\ne\infty, \\[10pt]
(x,y,z)=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \left( \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2},t \right) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

as that's kind of what you do when you parametrize a sphere, but it doesn't work. We have that $t=\dfrac{y}{x+1}$, so at $z=0$ we would have $y=0$, which wouldn't describe a circle at all.

Comment: I guess you have to use stereographic projection here.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it. As $\mathbb{R}^2\cup \{\infty\}$ is compact (as it is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$), the $2$-sphere is Hausdorff, and the stereographic projection is continuous, it follows that $\mathbb{R}^2\cup {\infty}$ is homeomorphic to the $2$-sphere. Does this look ok? Thanks

Comment: Looks fine but it is better if you explicitly write the stereographic projection